# Which standard flag should I use for a link-only answer that should be a comment?

Tags: discussion, flags

On this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710175/how-do-i-convert-voice-to-text-in-ios/45710338#45710338) (now deleted), I raised a custom flag that this is a link only answer *which should be converted to comment*.

> Following link may help you:
>   http://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework
>
> And its also have working code on github too.
>
> Thanks.. let me know need more help.
>
> I m not not an AppCode guy!!

The link was good and had the answer but we don't accept links as answer do we? At the same time, if I used standard flags like VLQ, the link would have been lost forever.

So I reckoned, maybe it is time to request the Mods to convert it into a comment as is their power. It looks like I was wrong however as moderator response was:

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and
>   resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of
>   standard flags: [see What is Flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Now I do have some 600+ helpful flags so it's not like I am unfamiliar with the standard flags. Was requesting the answer to be turned into a comment wrong use of custom flags? Since no one except mods can do it, it looked like fair use to me.

What standard flag am I supposed to use if I want the post to be converted into comment, not to be deleted completely by community reviews?

According to [dupe meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/4029561):

> Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still
>   an answer. You can downvote such posts to signal that the answer is a
>   bad answer, but it is still an answer.
>
> **This includes many link-only answers; posts that try to answer the question by pointing at a keyword that happens to be a link, or
>   similar.**

The link was pointing at a keyword which was the solution. So if that guidance is to be followed, should the custom flag to convert the post into a comment be declined?

Comment: @gnat According to that link: `Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still an answer. You can downvote such posts to signal that the answer is a bad answer, but it is still an answer.

This includes many link-only answers; posts that try to answer the question by pointing at a keyword that happens to be a link, or similar. `

That's different than the accepted answer here. Which guideline should I follow then?

Comment: siri-speech-framework is the keyword. **posts that try to answer the question by pointing at a keyword that happens to be a link**

Answer (score 5):

That is a textbook link-only answer. The *entirety* of the answer is buried behind the link. The link text doesn't even tell you anything meaningful.

Such posts should be flagged simply as "Not An Answer". You don't need a custom flag to explain why; the problems with the post are more than obvious.

Moderators can convert link-only answers to comments at their discretion when processing "Not An Answer" flags. And...if the community gets to it first and deletes it, well that's the risk ye takes when posting link-only answers.

Comment: I thought not an answer was for stuff which doesn't even attempt to solve the problem? Links are not considered as an attempt?

Comment: No. There is no answer there at all. The post does not meet our basic criteria for an answer, so it qualifies handily for "not an answer". If you can make any sense of [this guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), you'll see it is basically exhibit A.

Comment: Ah got it. It was just a sign pointing where the apple was so it's NAA. Thanks

Comment: would you care to weigh in the discussion below the main post?

Comment: Discussing that internally, @NSNoob. I disagree with it, naturally. But I did not realize it was the previous guidance, so I'm sorry for declining your flag.

Comment: No worry about that. the VLQ and NAA flag do confuse me a lot so I am happy to get a clearer picture here. Hope you will update your answer with the conclusion of your internal discussion.

Comment: I often use VLQ, leaving a comment, the reason is that if they edit the answer to included more info, the VLQ flag is automatically cleared. In general I think the correct answer to which flag should I use is: VLQ or NAA it should not make any difference, the outcome should be the same.

Comment: Sure, @Petter. VLQ would have worked just as well here. I am honestly not sure what the difference is, or whether there is any value in having them as two separate flags. Moderators pretty much evaluate them identically, as do users in the review queues. They both get interpreted as, "is this so bad it needs to be deleted?"